# CiviMail - CiviCRM (Drupal 7): Problem with attached documents

Tags: civimail, attachments

We are having a problem when sending emails with attached documents from CiviCRM and happens in both ways simple and bulk emails. Three months ago, we hadn’t this problem, we sent a bulk email last July with a PDF document attached with a size of 2 MB (approximately) and the mails arrived with the PDF without any problems.

Recently we tried to reproduce that same bulk email with also the same PDF but with a different group (a testing one) as recipients this time. The emails arrive to the recipients but without the corresponding attached document.

Right now, when we send emails with attached documents whose size is below 900 KB (approx.) the emails arrive correctly. But when the size of the attached document is below that, the email keeps arriving without the document.

And isnt appearing any error messages.

We would be grateful if anyone could give us some clue about this.

Thank you

- CiviCRM version: 4.2.7
- Drupal 7 version: 7.59

Comment: Is this helpful? https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19204

Comment: That says: Resolution: Fixed/Completed, Affects Version/s: 4.7.10, Fix Version/s: 4.7.11 - but may provide a clue

Comment: What is your Outbound mail set up?

Comment: Are your constituents using Gmail? Why not just upload them to Drive and paste the share link in the email. They will show up at the bottom of the email as though they were "attached".

Comment: Henry it might be better to embed a link to your PDF in your mailing rather than send it as an attachment. That avoids the problem. And will save you a lot of bandwidth!